# VBA, Open a comment threaded in the edit box (Excel 365, version 2211, 32 bits)

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a new comment threaded from my own popup menu and I want the user to be able to enter the text in the comment threaded box. Since there is no `Visible` property on the comments threaded, how can I show the comments threaded box?

The only way I can find to create a new threaded comment is with `.AddCommentThreaded("")`

The user then has to move the mouse over the cell to bring up the edit box and then press the pencil icon to edit the new note. This is unprofessional.

To open a comment (a note) in edit mode, I use `Application.SendKeys "+{F2}", True`
For example:

```
With MyCell
    .AddComment
    .Comment.Visible = True
    .Comment.Text Text:=Application.UserName & ":" & vbLf
    .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(1, Len(.Comment.Text) - 1).Font.Bold = True
    Application.SendKeys "+{F2}", True
End With
```

Is there any way to use something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved something close to the behavior of CommentThreaded in Excel.

[image]

There are two things that don't quite work, if someone could give me a solution I would appreciate it.:

1. I can't use `Application.SendKeys` to edit the comment in the edit
   box. The user must click the pencil icon to edit the new Comment
   Threaded. It seems that CommentThreaded doesn't support it.
2. If the sheet has frozen rows or columns ( `FreezePanes` ) the cell reference fails,
   the cursor does not move to the correct cell and, therefore, the
   edit box does not appear.

The popup menu will appear if you right click on `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10")`. This is the code:

In `Sheet1` code of a new workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(target, Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10")) Is Nothing Then
        Call MyPopUpMenu(target)
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

in a Module `Module1`:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
      ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
      ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Public gsPopUpMenuAction As String

Public Const gsPOPUPMENU As String = "TestMenu"

Sub DeletePopUpMenu()
    On Error Resume Next
    CommandBars(gsPOPUPMENU).Delete
    gsPopUpMenuAction = ""

End Sub

Sub MyPopUpMenu(ByRef rgCell As Range)
    
    Call ShowTestMenu
    
    Select Case gsPopUpMenuAction
    Case "NEW COMMENT_THREADED"
        With rgCell
            .AddCommentThreaded ("")
        End With
        With CellCoord.TopLeftPoint(rgCell)
            SetCursorPos .x, .y
        End With
    Case "NEW COMMENT"
        With rgCell
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Visible = True
            .Comment.Text Text:=Application.UserName & ":" & vbLf
            .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters( _
              1, Len(.Comment.Text) - 1).Font.Bold = True
            Application.SendKeys "+{F2}", True
        End With
    Case "DELETE COMMENT_THREADED"
        rgCell.ClearComments
    Case "DELETE COMMENT"
        rgCell.ClearComments
    Case "SHOW HIDE COMMENT"
        If rgCell.Comment.Visible = True Then
            rgCell.Comment.Visible = False
        Else
            rgCell.Comment.Visible = True
        End If
    End Select

End Sub

Sub ShowTestMenu()
    Call DeletePopUpMenu
    Call CreatePopUpMenu
    
    On Error Resume Next
    CommandBars(gsPOPUPMENU).ShowPopup
        
End Sub

Sub CreatePopUpMenu()
    With Application.CommandBars.Add _
      (Name:=gsPOPUPMENU, Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
        
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "New Comment Threaded"
            .OnAction = "NewCommentThreaded"
            .FaceId = 2031
        End With

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "New comment"
            .OnAction = "NewComment"
            .FaceId = 4385
        End With

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Delete comment threaded"
            .OnAction = "DeleteCommentThreaded"
            .FaceId = 1592
        End With

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Delete comment"
            .OnAction = "DeleteComment"
            .FaceId = 1592
        End With

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Show or hide commente"
            .OnAction = "ShowHideComment"
            .FaceId = 17380
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        Dim MyCell As String
        MyCell = ActiveCell.CommentThreaded.Parent
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Dim CommentThreadedYes As Boolean
            CommentThreadedYes = True
        End If
        Err.Clear
        
        MyCell = ActiveCell.Comment.Parent
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Dim CommentYes As Boolean
            CommentYes = True
        End If
        Err.Clear
        
        If CommentThreadedYes = True Or CommentYes = True Then
            .Controls(1).Visible = False
            .Controls(2).Visible = False
        End If
        
        If CommentThreadedYes = False And CommentYes = False Then
            .Controls(3).Visible = False
            .Controls(4).Visible = False
            .Controls(5).Visible = False
        End If
        
        If CommentThreadedYes = True Then
            .Controls(4).Visible = False
            .Controls(5).Visible = False
        End If
        
        If CommentYes = True Then
            .Controls(3).Visible = False
        End If
        
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub NewCommentThreaded()
    gsPopUpMenuAction = "NEW COMMENT_THREADED"
End Sub

Sub NewComment()
    gsPopUpMenuAction = "NEW COMMENT"
End Sub

Sub DeleteCommentThreaded()
    gsPopUpMenuAction = "DELETE COMMENT_THREADED"
End Sub

Sub DeleteComment()
    gsPopUpMenuAction = "DELETE COMMENT"
End Sub

Sub ShowHideComment()
    gsPopUpMenuAction = "SHOW HIDE COMMENT"
End Sub
```

In a Module `CellCoord` (code from https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/380495-solved-x-and-y-screen-coordinates-of-a-range.html)

```
'https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/380495-solved-x-and-y-screen-coordinates-of-a-range.html
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
      ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" ( _
      ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" ( _
      ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" ( _
      ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
      ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" ( _
      ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" ( _
      ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" ( _
      ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Sub Test()
    With TopLeftPoint(Selection)
        SetCursorPos .x, .y
    End With
End Sub

Private Function DPIfactors()
    Static sdArr(1 To 2) As Double
    Dim hdc As Long
    If sdArr(1) = 0 Then
        hdc = GetDC(0)
        sdArr(1) = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, 88) / 72  'Horz
        sdArr(2) = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, 90) / 72  'Vert
        ReleaseDC 0, hdc
    End If
    DPIfactors = sdArr
End Function

Public Function TopLeftPoint(ByRef rng As Range) As POINTAPI
    With TopLeftPoint
        Dim DZoom As Long
        DZoom = rng.Parent.Parent.Windows(1).Zoom
        .x = ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(rng.Left * DPIfactors(1) * DZoom / 100)
        .y = ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(rng.Top * DPIfactors(2) * DZoom / 100)
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a string as an argument to the `.AddCommentThreaded` method to fill-in the comment from the user. You just need to collect the comment from the user beforehand.

For instance, you could use and InputBox like this:

```vb
    Dim UserComment As String
    UserComment = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter your comment:", Title:="Comment thread", Type:=2)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").AddCommentThreaded UserComment
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks DecimalTurn, it's a good idea although I intend to do something as close to the original Excel process (show comment box after clicking the popup menu).

If, after creating the comment, I place (with the `SetCursorPos` API) the mouse pointer over the cell, the edit comment box is displayed.

But now I need to find a method to get the coordinates of the cell. I'm working on it because this topic is also complicated. I hope to answer my question when I have it solved.

Comment: this message would be better added as a comment to my original answer or as an edit to your original answer, since it is not really an answer to your question.